# Can I use one part of my primary key as a foreign key?

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema, sql-server-2014

I'm storing the results of some simulations in a database. A simulation is uniquely identified by its `ExperimentID`. Every simulation runs for some number of simulation cycles, incremented via `CycleCount`. So at Cycle 0, we get some data:

```
ExperimentID, CycleCount, data1, data2
0,            0,          100,   200
```

Then at cycle 1, we get more data:

```
ExperimentID, CycleCount, data1, data2
0,            0,          100,   200
0,            1,          150,   250
```

So, `data1` and `data2` are in their own tables to make sure the database is normalized. The composite key here is formed by `ExperimentID,CycleCount`. Can I use `CycleCount` to establish a relationship between `data1` and `data2` by using it as a foreign key? Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: Your foreign keys need to reference entire primary keys.

Comment: Okay, so I guess this isn't the way to go. If I'm logging multiple values for something like data1 over a given experiment, how should I be uniquely identifying them? My original thought process was that a piece of data can be uniquely identified by the experiment in which is was logged, and the cycle count of the experiment at which it was logged. I could be totally off base here, so feel free to correct me if I'm misinterpreting how to set this up.

Comment: "establish a relationship between data1 and data2 by using it as a foreign key" Unclear: What does "establish a relationship between" two columns mean? (To *have them in the same table/relation* is to *record* an associated relation/relationship between them.) How are you "using it as a foreign key"? "I'm logging multiple values for something like data1 over a given experiment, how should I be uniquely identifying them?" By simulation cycle: experiment+cyclecount. (As you go on to say.) But your *question* is unclear, in particular what FK and PK you are talking about (in question & title).

Comment: So an ExperimentIDs identifies a simulation and an ExperimentID + cycle# identifies a simulation cycle. But what you are asking is unclear. "data1 and data2 are in their own tables to make sure the database is normalized": Since they're in the same table here, maybe you mean something like that you have another table with more info about each? Or maybe you mean they are in their own table (singular) (disinct from an experiment,/simulation table) and this is that table? And please explain the normalization.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "A simulation is uniquely identified by its ExperimentID," you are saying there is a table, called Experiments possibly, where this field is the primary key. In the Simulations table, this value is a foreign key to the Experiments table, but it cannot be the PK of this table. This table contains simulations and there can be several simulations for each experiment. So, yes, the combination (ExperimentID, CycleCount) makes an excellent PK for this table, as long as CycleCount is unique within each experiment.

If CycleCount is just an incrementing value, then it doesn't make sense for it to be a foreign key. It would just be referring to a table of incrementing values which really adds nothing to the data.

If, however, each cycle has a fixed meaning and you can create a table like this:

```
Cycle  Name     Meaning
    0  Initial  This is the initial reading taken before...
    1  PreFlow  This is the first reading taken after the proper flow rate is established...
    2  MidFlow  This is the second reading taken in the middle of the flow...
    3  PostFlow This is the final reading taken after the flow has stopped...
```

then CycleCount as a FK to this table would make sense. It defines the domain of CycleCount so you can't have a value of 8 or 17 or anything other than 0..3 and provides additional information of each cycle you may want to show in some queries.

If such a table is not needed, you should explicitly limit the domain with a check constraint in the `create table` statement:

```
    CycleCount tinyint check( CycleCount between 0..3 )
```

Being defined as part of the PK will prevent duplicate values from being used for the same experiment.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is not a great normalisation.
Given that you could have different experiment IDs, you definitely cannot use CycleCount as an unique identifier.
You should also tell us about possible other tables or details about what you specifically mean "relationship between" data1 and data2.
This is also perhaps better suited to [dba.stackexchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Essentially, I'm trying to mimic a spreadsheet logging capability I currently have set up. There's an example spreadsheet here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/116513/68552, with an explanation of column names a little further down, in the comment chain on this answer: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/116651/68552

Comment: Well, OK, but Excel has an "internal" unique ID for every row - the row number. I strongly suggest that you create a plain old `id` column as auto_increment and use that as primary key instead of a multiple key.

Comment: Oh! So If I just use an auto incrementing int (or GUID) as my primary key, I can still keep experiment data together by using the "Where" clause. Is that right?

Comment: Exactly, you can query for a single experiment using `where ExperimentID = x`.
It is advisable to create a plain index on the `ExperimentID` column if you will presumably have quite some data (e.g. tens of thousands to millions of rows) in the same table, in order to speed up the conditional retrieval.

Comment: Is plain index a data type? Also, would I need to create two new tables that links GUID to ExperimentID and CycleCount respectively? Or would they remain in the table with the data1? Would they be foreign keys?

Comment: No, the exact reason I recommended using autoincrement instead of GUID because you do not actually need it until you start to use multiple tables for whatever yet unclear reason.

Comment: Plain index is well, just an index.
It is not related to data, it just makes sequential searching faster.

Comment: Primary keys are always indexed, but if you wish to search or retrieve selectively based on another column, you should create an index on each and every such column as well.

Comment: So you think I should just stored all of the experiment data in one table? Wouldn't that make it not normalized?

Comment: If you are having (in the example) two and *exactly two* outputs from *every* experiment, then you do not need to split your data into more tables.
Relational database is relational, and as such, they "shine" most when used to one-to-many or many-to-many relations.
If, however, you will e.g. use a looooong name for each experiment, then storing the experiment with an unique id and name, and storing the output in another table referencing the "name" (experiment) by ID might make sense.

Comment: Each experiment has about 40 columns of data. The number of columns does not change from simulation to simulation. The amount of data (length of time/number of rows per experiment) for a given experimen does vary though. I like the idea about names, that would give me the ability to given each experiment a unique description. So essentially, I'd have primary key (autoincrement), experimentID, CycleCount, and then 40 columns of data, all in one table. Right?

Comment: Yes, if the data count is fairly equal, no need to split them.
Normalisation is to reduce redundance, while here the only redundance I see could be the experiment ID.

Comment: @ijustlovemath & Victor: The (candidate) key is experimentID + CycleCount. There's no need for an additional column or (candidate) key. ExperimentID is not redundant, it is necessary to identify the experiment of the cycle of the data values from a cycle number. (See TommCatt's answer.)